# Convert int to 2 bytes of Big-Endian

Tags: python, int, hex, endianness

I have a problem converting an int to 2 hex bytes of Big-Endian encoding.

for example:

```
import struct

a = 1234
struct.pack('>I', a)
```

what I receive is:

```
'\x00\x00\x04\xd2'
```

what I wish to receive is (2 bytes of hex):

```
'0x04', '0xd2'
```

I have no idea of how to get this result, I have tried different cutting and moving techniques in order to get the result I wish from every 4 numbers integer but yet sometimes 0's are interfering with correct result.

What is the correct way of receiving this 2 byte hex value of big-endian encoded integer?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Use the `>H` [format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-strings);
Example in Python 2:

```
>>> import struct
>>> a = 1234
>>> s = struct.pack('>H', a)
```

Then you unpack it;

```
>>> first, second = struct.unpack('>BB', s)
>>> first
4
>>> second
210
```

---

If you are using Python 3, you can use `to_bytes`:

```
In [1]: a = 1234

In [2]: a.to_bytes(2, 'big')
Out[2]: b'\x04\xd2'

In [3]: b = bytearray(a.to_bytes(2, 'big'))

In [4]: b[0]
Out[4]: 4

In [5]: b[1]
Out[5]: 210
```

Comment: I think it would be a plus point to give a short description of what both formats are.

Comment: Hey, I have tried doing this, when I append this struct command to a variable and print it I get like a strange picture instead of "\x0d\xd2". Moreover, I would like to receive the output as 2 bytes.. 0x04 and 0xd2

Comment: The short description can be found in the official documentation for the `struct` module, to which I've added a link. A real explanation would require a significant history lesson. :-)

Comment: @wannabebetter The output of `struct.pack` is a string of bytes. If you print that, what will come out will depend on your terminal settings.

Comment: Hey, all your post is using the terminal and not written code. Moreover, the format you are offering is on an "edited" string (0x{:04x}'). I wish to get the end result of an output of 2 hex bytes. I do not see how I make it work with this "manual" formatting.

Comment: You say you want hex bytes, but your question shows two strings... Anyway, if you want the bytes, use `unpack` as shown in the modified answer.